# Can appcelerator titanium build apps for Kindle E-reader

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Can Appcelerator titanium  be used to develop kindle e-reader (not fire) apps?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titanium Mobile only supports Android, iOS, Mobile Web (HTML5) and BlackBerry (beta) SDKs.

Kindle e-readers use the Kindle Development Kit (KDK) which is not based on Android.